# Focus issues with react

Tags: reactjs, ref

Focus is not working on the input when "isFocussed" is true

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.isFocussed){
    this.myRef.current.focus();
  }
}
```

```
<input ref={this.myRef} />
```

Comment: Please share some more code atleast your component

Comment: are you getting any error? or just focus not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `createRef` and trying to use `focus` method which is the issue.
Simply create `callback ref` and you are good to go.

Here is the working code below and [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-feather-9n5m4).

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import FocusComp from "./FocusComp";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    focus: false
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ focus: true })}>
          click me to focus
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <FocusComp isFocussed={this.state.focus} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

FocusComp.js

```
import React from "react";

class FocusComp extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isFocussed) {
      this.myRef.focus();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <input ref={myRef => (this.myRef = myRef)} />;
  }
}

export default FocusComp;
```

I created a working code to make you understand what you did wrong.

**Things to improve:-**

1) use `createRef` instead of callback.

2) Don't use `componentWillReceiveProps` as it's deprecated.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: @FE_Addict - Glad to know that.